# Set base_path for a package in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

Here's my config.yml file

```
framework:
#code
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
    #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    packages:
      blade:
        base_path: '/bundle/bladecms'
#code
```

I'd like to set base_path for blade prefix to be able to use

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/image.png', 'blade') }}"/>
```

instead

```
<img src="{{ asset('bundle/bladecms/images/image.png') }}"/>
```

So what's a problem? When I use 'base_path' I get

```
Unrecognized option "base_path" under "framework.templating.packages.blade"
```

If I change base_path to base_url I get

```
"/bundle/bladecms" is not a valid URL
```

How to configure it properly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a valid URL (e.g. `http://yourhost/bundle/bladecms`) .

Make your configuration like this :

```
framework:
    templating:
        packages:
            blade:
                assets_base_urls: '%router.request_context.scheme%://%router.request_context.host%/bundle/bladecms
```

And use it like follows :

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/image.png', 'blade') }}"/>
```

The first parameter `router.request_context.scheme` is the protocol used by the request (i.e. `http`, `ssl`).
The second `router.request_context.host` is the host of the request.

Like this, your `base_url` change dynamically depending on the request.

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets-base-urls